# incorrect body content ngx.location.capture

Tags: curl, nginx, lua, recaptcha

I want to detect correct google captcha data (API2) using lua+nginx

I want to use `ngx.location.capture` function.

Nginx config (party):

```
location = /recaptcha/api/siteverify {
        resolver   8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://www.google.com;
        }
```

Part of lua code:

```
local res = ngx.location.capture("/recaptcha/api/siteverify", {method = ngx.HTTP_POST,args ={ secret = "<MY_SECRET_KEY>", response = resp, remoteip = ip} })
```

In this case I recieve incorrect 'binary' `res.body` data:

```
["�RPP*.MNN-.V�R()*M��
```

or in nginx logs:

```
 ▒▒RPP*.MNN-.V▒RHK▒)N▒▒▒▒▒&秤▒ģ▒B@▒▒▒▒▒̼t▒̼▒▒ݢ▒▒▒▒T%▒d,W-▒)▒▒K
```

I if you pure `curl ... -X POST https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverif` bash command with the same request, I receive correct data:

```
{
  "success": false
}
```

Why it can occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proxy_pass_request_headers off;`  in nginx configure file solves the prolem.

```
location = /recaptcha/api/siteverify {
internal;
resolver   8.8.8.8;
proxy_pass https://www.google.com;
proxy_pass_request_headers off;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in Magento 1.7.0.2 in 3rd party extension. Got such data in answer only on specific server

```
‹       «жRPP*.MNN-.VІR()*MХ  %g$жд¤жҐ§Ж—ЂД•ЊНu
Ќt
CM¬L¬Ќў”А*3т‹KтsSAЄЉJіуSRs2уТхЉJ•ёjЊЗЂ¶^
```

Changing nginx settings was not helped. It turned out that it is gzipped answer.
We have changed CURLOPT_ENCODING to deflate and issue was resolved.